# Full width accordion on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Two-column fluid grid. I have a media query for a bootstrap accordion at mobile. I want the accordion to span the full width of the screen at mobile, like my fixed-top navbar.

I applied the below css to the accordion, and it does overide the .container sizing, but now my right-column is now floating top/left position, with the accordion on top of it. How do I address this?

```
.accordion {
  position: fixed;  
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}



#right-column {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for an answer to your problem? Or for the name of a forum?

Comment: Asking for resources like a forum it's offtopic, so I removed that part of your question. You can rollback the edit and take your chances if you want but I would not recommend it.